# Run Application in tray icon(not in taskbar)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, system-tray

I want to run my app in the tray but I don't the icon in the taskbar.

I using my JFrame in Hide_On_Close operation

and I using a tray icon for notifications but how to get rid of the icon on the taskbar while my GUI application running.

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing? You run your application, and show a JFrame, then you close the application and you want it to appear in the system tray?

Comment: sorry for not being accurate

Comment: what I am doing is a widget which needs to be in the tray but not in taskbar

Comment: so I have to hide the icon on the taskbar only.

Comment: The tray is only for notifications. The task bar has a list of open applications, and your's is, while open, and application.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use System Tray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html) for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? You might need to add what os you're working on.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
public class SysTrayFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("systray test");
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        BufferedImage img =  new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 64, 64);
        g.dispose();
        JButton b = new JButton("click to hide");
        frame.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(evt-> frame.setVisible(false) );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(img);
        icon.addActionListener( evt->{
            System.out.println("doing it");
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
        SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(icon);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using windows 10 pro

Comment: @TheFox-CodersAcademy it also might have to do with how you start the app. Does your jdk come with both, java.exe and javaw.exe, Using javaw might mean the app won't show up i the taskbar when it doesn't have an associated window.